# Multiple Unique Author Profiles

Tags: author, users, profiles

I'd like to create multiple user profiles are unique, without just using a "if/then/else" php statement on the author.php template?
All I need is the ability to create two different types of profiles.

Comment: How do you want to identify the different types of profiles?  By user level, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could register a user_meta field (probably a dropdown) and use that to select templates. You will still need to use `if` statements to differentiate the templates, but you're going to need that regardless of the route you take. If you use `get_template_part()` you can split out the actual html and such of it and just handle the logic in author.php